# Default Custom Fields in Developer Orgs

Tags: developer-edition

Have anyone aware why there are some custom fields coming under certain objects whenever we get registered for a new Developer Org? I expect that there would be only standard fields.

Comment: I presume the idea is to demonstrate some basic customisation. But yes it would be good if there was an easy way to avoid that (and even better if there was an easy way to avoid the many components added when sites are turned on).

Comment: True. Recently worked on developing appechange app and when creating orgs for package testing and migrating noted this. I expected only standard components and my ones, which was not

Comment: Yeah easy to accidentally add those custom components that come in the developer edition org.